# What is the exact use of Transform in Unity3D? and a code sample I am dealing with

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform, gameobject, grid-system

I am intermediate unity developer and still in progress of learning curve.
I am stuck with the use of transform game object. I know it holds position, rotation and scale properties but, I am following an tetris clone to enlarge my skills, I really have difficult times to understand. Please, do not think this only as tetris games, I have difficult times this situation with the games which has grid system in 2 dimension.

I will share a kind of code below and I am really do not exactly understanding what is happening but only undestanding on instinct.

Developer following steps like creating an Transform[,] grid array and trying to assign block datas to this grid array, than updating the grid according to moving blocks etc. that's cool. But I can not understanding what is happening there with the code, because I can not shape that in my mind with the process.

A code sample here;

```
// will be called from tetromino script
public void UpdateGrid(Tetromino tetromino)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < gridHeight; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < gridWidth; x++)
        {
            // if there is a current existing tetromino in the grid coordinate
            if (grid[x, y] != null) // registered mino at this position 
            {
                // check to is if the tetromino is there
                // if the parent transform is the tetromino transform that is send as parameter
                if (grid[x,y].parent == tetromino.transform)
                {
                    grid[x, y] = null; // updating the grid
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // updates our grid
    foreach (Transform mino in tetromino.transform)
    {
        Vector2 pos = Round(mino.position);

        if (pos.y < gridHeight)
        {
            // storing mino with transform in that position
            grid[(int)pos.x, (int)pos.y] = mino;
        }                
    }
}
```

In this code sample, what do I have to understand? What grid represents here? a dot? an empty game object? and what is happening here?

Is he assigning transform "mino" as a reference of the mino block object there?

I really have hard times with the Transform grid system and many kind of games as 2048 or crushing games, or tetris games etc. has this kind of grid system.

Can you please help me to understand the relation between Transform grid and mino blocks in the scene?

I am really trying to learn game development and spending very much time trying to learn it. I am feeling I am developing but sometimes I am having hard bumps on my way. Grid system is very important to track moving objects or blocks in games and I want to have a pure understanding of it.

Comment: The tutorial I think you're watching does explain it

Comment: not giving a vast idea what is happening there. Generally instructors are going very fast in some point.

Answer (score 0):

Ok mixing up terminology will add to your confusion.

In its mind it has an array called grid to work out whether things can move or not - while you've not shown how the grid is defined, it would be specific in how it was defined so probably Transform[,] grid = new Transform[x,y] where x and y is the size of the grid its thinking of in terms of width and height of a physical grid representing the play area.

In short, `Transform mino in tetromino.transform` gets all the child components and goes through them 1 by 1
In tetris it is often referred to as the 4 blocks that make the tetris shape are known as mino's where as the final shape is a Tetromino, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetromino

using an array to decide if all the squares can move down 1 or not, is easier than trying to move an object and have unity decide if it fits or not.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, It is not completely answering my question because I am wondering the existing of transform and game object relation in a grid. But I could find a way to debug my code, and I see that the code "grid[x,y]" represents mino itself not tetromino. So, It is checking like is this mino belongs to the parent which I send you as a parameter? At least I could solve this.

Comment: @silkworm tbh your post had too many questions in, normally its 1 question per post.  However, think back to how they explained making the shapes, this is important to how the transform comes into it.

Comment: I guess the most complicated part for me to understand the code here, why we first ask that there is a mino?  with the code (grid[x,y] != null) and if there is a mino we assign that as null, then again in second loop we say that we are assigning this mino to this grid back. To be spesific, this part is my main problem I guess. Why we delete it and assign it back to same grid every time?

Comment: If you step through the code, following what it does.  The first procedure removes the piece  from its current location in the grid, the second one adds it in.

Comment: Yes I understand what the code is doing there, but I dont understand why is it being done?  What is the trick of deleting and assigning it back?

That is my question. And also thanks for your answers.

Comment: Partyly cos thats how they designed it, secondly thats how they show it dropping down the grid.

Comment: May be to keep track of last position of the mino because it is dynamically moving down. But still confused and I really appreciate your effort to help.